# What are the "special items" Delvin is looking for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In my travels across Skyrim, I've encountered a handful of items which possess *particular* value.  A Dwemer Puzzle Cube here, a Jeweled Candlestick there… normally such things are hard to find buyers for, but Delvin's always been there to take them off my hands.

Unfortunately, he also plays his cards close to his chest and doesn't seem inclined to simply *ask* for particular items, seeming to prefer I stumble across them naturally.  *I*, however, do *not*.  I intend to be running this merry band of thieves soon and want a well-stocked trophy case.

What, and where, are all the special items Delvin is seeking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The items Delvin will buy off you are:

- Queen Bee Statue in the Goldenglow Estate
- Honningbrew Decanter in the Honningbrew Meadery
- East Empire Shipping Map in the East Empire Company Warehouse
- Model Ship in the Snow Veil Sanctum
- Dwemer Puzzle Cube in Calcelmo's Laboratory through the Dwemer Museum
- Bust of the Gray Fox in Riftweald Manor
- Left Eye of the Falmer which is found on Mercer's body during the quest Blindsighted

[Source 1](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Miscellaneous_Items#Trinkets)

[Source 2](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Litany_of_Larceny)

Comment: This list doesn't seem to be complete.  If nothing else, I've found a Jeweled Candlestick (I've forgotten where I've picked it up) and sold it to Delvin.  It appears on the "display shelves" in the cistern, just like the items listed here.

Comment: @BenBlank Those objects are for Vex, not Delvin, as detailed here http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Burglary_Job

Comment: As far as I'm aware, those don't show up on the trophy shelves.  I thought I picked it up before joining the Thieves Guild, as well.  Hmm.

Comment: @BenBlank As seen here: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#Larceny_Targets they do begin to show up on the shelf, not sure exactly when they show up, but they do.

Comment: @BenBlank Because all of the rare items are part of a single quest, once you've picked up the Dwemer Puzzle Cube (for example) it's too late to turn in any of the items before it.

Comment: @agf Actually that's not true, I missed the Queen Bee Statue, the map and the bust of the gray fox, and turned them all in after I'd already become Guild Master.

Comment: @MrSmooth You sure? If you look at http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Litany_of_Larceny you'll see that it's a single quest. Quests can only move forward in stages, not back. And I missed the Dwemer Puzzle Cube until after I'd already turned in later items, and I have no quest for it or dialogue with Devlin.

Comment: @agf I'm sure, but it was a bit buggy. When I picked up the Bust, which was the last item I needed, I had 3 items left to turn in, but it auto completed the quest without giving me any money, so I reloaded a previous save, handed the others in and then picked up the bust, and then I couldn't give the bust to him rendering the quest unable to be completed. So it's a bit odd in how it works.

Comment: @agf — I guarantee that you can turn them in out-of-order; I've done so. TES quest stages aren't a sequence of steps, they're a collection of flags. You can't unset a flag, but you can set them in any order. (Though most quests don't do that.)